# Netgear router static IP

Tags: router, port-forwarding, static-ip

I've recently acquired a new router, a Netgear WNDR4000. I promptly went to set up a static internal IP so I could port forward for the Minecraft Server I run on my computer.

I've done this with previous routers and I know how to do it. However, every time I log off on my computer and log back on, I find I have no Internet connection. If I go to Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections, and I look at my connection, when I go to the IPv4 properties, the Default Gateway box is blank.

I'm not sure what's causing this; any ideas?

Important specs and other notes:

- Running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
- Desktop using wired connection but computer is wireless capable

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention it works perfectly without the static IP setup.

Comment: Not sure why this would be happening, but it should have nothing to do with your new router. If it does, the only thing I can think of is that your computer is somehow accepting incomplete DHCP settings. I would just make sure that my firmware was up-to-date and try entering the gateway again, and hope it stays.

Comment: Why can't you just have the router assign a static DHCP lease to that computer?

Comment: DD-WRT used to have a very similar problem when you used the wrong browser.  Have you tried it in IE or Firefox?

Comment: Does it happen just with this router?  In Windows machine, you have the option to accept a DHCP gateway or specify your own.  What does the computer say in the TCP/IP configuration

Comment: Did you install any of the management software that comes with these new routers?  Just asking b/c that could be a potential gateway from your router to your O.S.

Comment: After a lot more research and exploring of the router, I figured out how to reserve the IP for that computer router-side. Mostly thanks to MaQleod, but Thank you everyone for your time.